# ASP.NET AJAX Preview 6 Conditional Attributes

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I am doing some training with the ASP.NET AJAX Preview 6 and VS2010 - I am using an example which has conditional attributes on the list item element to change the class, the example is here:

```
<ul class="sys-template">
  <li class:fired={{Fired}}>
    {{Name}} ({{ Title }})
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now this works fine when i use the Preview 4 scripts but with the Preview 6 scripts it doesn't work.  Does anyone know why ?

- Russ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<li sys:class-fired={{Fired}}>`